# .NET 3.5 Dispose Registry Key

Tags: c#, dispose, static-analysis, registrykey

I have the following code:

```
RegistryKey installKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(installKey);
```

I am running a static analysis tool on my code and it is giving me a defect saying that I am returning from the medthod without disposing **installKey**. I know you can call Dispose() on RegistryKey in .NET 4.0 or later but my code runs on .NET 3.5.

Does anybody know the best way to Dispose this RegistryKey and keep my static analysis tool happy?

Comment: in 3.5 it was `RegistryKey.close()` not `dispose`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should wrap your code within a `using` block, which will implicitly call `Dispose` for you .  It's unclear what static analysis tool you're using, but hopefully it understands `using`:

```
using (RegistryKey installKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(installKey))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Note that you can also call `Dispose` explicitly, but you need to cast `RegistryKey` to `IDisposable` first:

```
((IDisposable)installKey).Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can be disposed in version 3.5!
See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Use a `using` block, as in trhe MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or simply call Dispose() like in any other IDisposable object.

Comment: You cant call Dispose() on it in .NET 3.5, you get this error: Error 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My apologies Jens, Tung has explained to me how you can call Dispose explicitly.

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the hint. But then I do not understand the documentation (see link) that is explicitly written for the .NET Framework 3.5 version and states that RegistryKey has an "Explicit Interface Implementation" of 'IDisposable.Dispose'. Where is my misunderstanding?