# How to properly close RegistryKey when chaining them to search for key?

Tags: c#, registry, idisposable

I'm using the following method to search for a key in the registry and return it's value. I pass in a root key to search from and the relative path of the target as a string. As I parse the path, I use the previous key as a base to open the next level.  I'ts strictly read-only so, is it necessary to close the base key after I am done with it?  And if so, is this the way to do it?

```
public static string QueryRegistry (RegistryKey root, string path)
{
    return path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
    .Aggregate(root, (r, k) =>
    {
        var key = r?.OpenSubKey(k);
        r?.Close();
        return key;
    }).GetValue(null).ToString();
}
```

Comment: `RegistryKey` is `IDisposable`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9905046/1132334. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.90).aspx) suggests that is is sufficient to wrap the topmost key in `using`

Comment: @dlatikay where it suggests that it is sufficient to only dispose root key?

Comment: Ok, yes, I knew it was `IDisposable` but I wasn't sure how to apply a using statement across function calls. Why only the top-most key?

Comment: in their example, they're using `tempKey` from `openSubkey` without closing/explicit Dispose(). `RegistryKey` builds on [SafeHandle](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,ee2cc83fa843892c), and `OpenSubKey` gets another handle, and the implementation of `RegistryKey` does not show any mechanism to keep track of subsequent handles opened and disposing them along. So I *guess* (and therefore its a comment), that sub keys retrieved with `OpenSubKey` should also be properly disposed to not leak their handles.

Comment: The only key named "tempKey" in their example is wrapped in using. So I would not assume any such behavior - better to dispose all keys.

Comment: you are right... how could I have not seen this.

Comment: It _does_ imply that `Dispose` is sufficient though so that's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your basic problem here is that you're creating an indeterminate number of `IDisposable` objects, and you're not sure when you'll be ready to close them.  What I do in a situation like this is create a collection to track them, and then dispose everything in the collection when I'm done.  There's some risk here that you won't properly dispose your objects though.

```
public static string QueryRegistry (RegistryKey root, string path)
{
    List<IDisposable> resourceTracker = new List<IDisposable>() { root };
    string ret = null;
    try 
    {
        ret = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        .Aggregate(root, (r, k) =>
        {
            var key = r?.OpenSubKey(k);
            if (key != null) 
            {
                resourceTracker.Add(key);
            }
            return key;
        }).GetValue(null).ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var res in resourceTracker)
        {
            res.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You could try to do this in a CER, but I'm pretty sure opening the new keys count as allocations which mean the CLR wouldn't treat it as a CER anyway.  But this should probably be safe enough.

This could be abstracted into a collection (somewhat like rory.ap suggested) like so:

```
public class DisposableCollection : IList<IDisposable>, IDisposable
{
    private List<IDisposable> disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

    #region IList<IDisposable> support

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(IDisposable item)
    {
        return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, IDisposable item)
    {
        ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Add(IDisposable item)
    {
        ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(IDisposable item)
    {
        return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(IDisposable[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(IDisposable item)
    {
        return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IDisposable> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<IDisposable> range)
    {
        disposables.AddRange(range);
    }

    public IDisposable this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables)[index];
        }

        set
        {
            ((IList<IDisposable>)disposables)[index] = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach(var disposable in disposables)
                {
                    disposable.Dispose();
                }
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~DisposableCollection() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    #endregion
}
```

Which could then be used like:

```
public static string QueryRegistry (RegistryKey root, string path)
{
    string ret = null;
    using (var resourceTracker = new DisposableCollection() { root })
    {
        ret = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        .Aggregate(root, (r, k) =>
        {
            var key = r?.OpenSubKey(k);
            if (key != null) 
            {
                resourceTracker.Add(key);
            }
            return key;
        }).GetValue(null).ToString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That class could be extended a bit as well to work in concurrent situations (say using a `ConcurrentBag` or `ConcurrentQueue`), and could be extended for other more specific needs (like a collection of `RegistryKey`s), and would be useful if you find yourself needing this logic in multiple places.

Comment: You could also make a disposable collection of the keys, and then just use a `using` block on the collection.  The collection's `Dispose` method would loop through and dispose of each.  Might be more robust, but yes a little more work.  However, its a re-usable pattern so it might be worth it.

Comment: Good idea - I edited to give an example of at least abstracting out the collection more generically.  I'm not sure how much value would get added by doing this specifically for `RegistryKey` rather than `IDisposable`, since the collection really only cares about calling `Dispose()`, but that depends on other use cases this might have in the app I suppose.

Comment: Hi @DanField, this is a brilliant solution for the case of undetermined lifecycle. In my case I know that the key is no longer required after I have used it's `.OpenSubKey` method to get the next level.  That means I know when to close them. Given that, is there any problem with my method? Is there any advantage in wrapping in a `using` statement, or in bulk disposal, compared to individual disposal?

Comment: The using statement encapsulates that try/finally logic to ensure dispose is called

Comment: Ok, so are you saying that I should really have a try/finally around the 'Close/Dispose` every iteration, to  manage the risk of error on dispose? Is that the problem with my naive solution? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yeah, if an exception were to occur you could miss actually closing/disposing and risk leaking an unmanaged resource (a handle to the registry)